# UIBlurEffect in TableView appears to twitch or move in background upon transition

Tags: ios, ios8

I have a background image that I'm passing from the main view controller to a details table view controller and using UIBlurEffect to make the image the background view of the details table view. The only problem is when I transition between view controllers, the background image appears to twitch/move at the edges of the image immediately after the transition. Only way I can stop it is if I set the alpha of the background to be higher.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's in the image and background? Is there some kind of distortion like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Answer (score 1):

The [UIVisualEffectView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html) (of which UIBlurEffect is a subclass) states:

> When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are less than 1. Creating views that are partially transparent causes the system to combine the view and all the associated subviews during an offscreen render pass. UIVisualEffectView objects need to be combined as part of the content they are layered on top of in order to look correct. Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all.

It sounds like this might be what you're doing. I was running into a similar problem and setting the background alpha to 1 was the only way I found to resolve the problem.